# Extract all URL links from CSS file

Tags: javascript

I have a asset file with CSS and that contains properties as: 
`background-image: url(my-url.jpg)`
Im trying to extract all images from the url(). How can i achieve that in JS?

Comment: Have you made any attempts? Can you show us your code? How far did you get, what went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the style sheet is loaded to the page, you can get the [StyleSheetList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheetList), and pick your style sheet using [`document.styleSheets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/styleSheets). After selecting the style sheet, iterate it's rules with [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=b), extract the backgroundImage url using a regular expression, and if the result is not `null` (we have a url), push it into the `urls` array:

You can can get relevant s

```js
const result = [...document.styleSheets[0].rules]
  .reduce((urls, { style }) => {
    var url = style.backgroundImage.match(/url\(\"(.+)\"\)/);
      
    url && urls.push(url[1]);
  
    return urls;
  }, []);
  
console.log(result);
```

```css
.bg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.a {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200);
}

.b {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg a"></div>

<br />

<div class="bg b"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.match()`, `.map()` and `.replace()`

```
let res = CSSText.match(/url\(.+(?=\))/g).map(url => url.replace(/url\(/, ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

I've extended @guest271314's answer with jQuery ajax. You may use it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("main.css", function(cssContent){
        let res = cssContent.match(/url\(.+(?=\))/g).map(url => url.replace(/url\(/, ""));
        alert( res );       
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote an updated version of this that iterates of all stylesheets on the page:

```js
let css_urls = [...document.styleSheets]
  .filter(sheet => {
    try { return sheet.cssRules }
    catch {}
  })
  .flatMap(sheet => Array.from(sheet.cssRules))
  .filter(rule => rule.style)
  .filter(rule => rule.style.backgroundImage !== '')
  .filter(rule => rule.style.backgroundImage !== 'initial')
  .filter(rule => rule.style.backgroundImage.includes("url"))
  .reduce((urls, {style}) => {
    urls.push(style.backgroundImage);
    return urls;
  }, []);
  
console.log(css_urls);
```