# Simple html dom to get background-image URL from style css

Tags: php, css

I am trying to get image url from `<style>` css code using simple html dom. but i don't get image url.

I wants to get `hd-banner-image` image url from here:

```
<div id="gh-banner">
    <style>
        #c4-header-bg-container {
            background-image: url(//yt3.ggpht.com/5oabquJr1cMEhL0GSyaeim5K78FLxILh4hXJBxIU3NnbpoVLMvquA6l2cbn7cTaFiRNRM2Vy-A=w1060-fcrop64=1,00005a57ffffa5a8-nd-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no);
        }

        @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
        screen and (min-resolution: 1.5dppx) {
            #c4-header-bg-container {
                background-image: url(//yt3.ggpht.com/5oabquJr1cMEhL0GSyaeim5K78FLxILh4hXJBxIU3NnbpoVLMvquA6l2cbn7cTaFiRNRM2Vy-A=w2120-fcrop64=1,00005a57ffffa5a8-nd-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no);
            }
        }

        #c4-header-bg-container .hd-banner-image {
            background-image: url(//yt3.ggpht.com/5oabquJr1cMEhL0GSyaeim5K78FLxILh4hXJBxIU3NnbpoVLMvquA6l2cbn7cTaFiRNRM2Vy-A=w2120-fcrop64=1,00005a57ffffa5a8-nd-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no);
        }
    </style>
</div>
```

I'm trying this below code:

```
$banner = $html->find('div#gh-banner style',0)->find('#c4-header-bg-container .hd-banner-image')->background-image;

echo $banner;
```

But result is empty.

How to i get `hd-banner-image` url using simple html dom? Help me to solve it. thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract all URL links from CSS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46877244/extract-all-url-links-from-css-file)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, style information is not available in DOM. They are all just an inner text of the style tag. Using regex and atring search is possible.

```
<?php

require getcwd().'/simple_html_dom.php';
$html = '<div id="gh-banner">
    <style>
        #c4-header-bg-container {
            background-image: url(//yt3.ggpht.com/5oabquJr1cMEhL0GSyaeim5K78FLxILh4hXJBxIU3NnbpoVLMvquA6l2cbn7cTaFiRNRM2Vy-A=w1060-fcrop64=1,00005a57ffffa5a8-nd-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no);
        }

        @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
        screen and (min-resolution: 1.5dppx) {
            #c4-header-bg-container {
                background-image: url(//yt3.ggpht.com/5oabquJr1cMEhL0GSyaeim5K78FLxILh4hXJBxIU3NnbpoVLMvquA6l2cbn7cTaFiRNRM2Vy-A=w2120-fcrop64=1,00005a57ffffa5a8-nd-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no);
            }
        }

        #c4-header-bg-container .hd-banner-image {
            background-image: url(//yt3.ggpht.com/5oabquJr1cMEhL0GSyaeim5K78FLxILh4hXJBxIU3NnbpoVLMvquA6l2cbn7cTaFiRNRM2Vy-A=w2120-fcrop64=1,00005a57ffffa5a8-nd-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no);
        }
    </style>
</div>';
$html = str_get_html($html);
$style = $html->find('div#gh-banner style',0)->innertext;
$string = preg_match('/hd-banner-image*.*[\s]+background-image:[\s]+url*.*/',$style,$matches);
$substring = substr($matches[0],strpos($matches[0],'(')+1);
$substring = substr($substring,0,strpos($substring,')'));
echo $substring;
```